# Boost::serialization and boost::mpi to broadcast derived class via base class pointer

Tags: c++, openmpi, boost-serialization, boost-mpi

I am trying to use boost::mpi::broadcast to send a derived class to all nodes via a base class pointer.  To do this, I am using the boost::serialization library to serialize my classes.  My code, however, does not compile and I get the errors "class boost::mpi::packed_skeleton_iarchive’ has no member named ‘append’" and "class boost::mpi::packed_skeleton_iarchive’ has no member named ‘reset’."

Here is the rough source code for the program:

```
// Base.hpp
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>

class Base
{
    public:
        Base() {}
        virtual ~Base() {}

        virtual void foo() = 0;
    private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;

        template<class Archive>
        void serialize( Archive& /*ar*/, const unsigned int /*version*/ ) {}
}

// Derived.hpp
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <vector>

#include "Base.hpp"

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
        Derived( int param );
        virtual ~Derived();

        void foo();
    private:
        int param_;
        std::vector< boost::shared_ptr > bar_;

        friend class boost::serialization::access;

        template<class Archive>
        void serialize( Archive& ar, const unsigned int /*version*/ )
        {
            ar & param_;
            ar & bar_;

            ar & boost::serialization::base_object< Base >( *this );
        }
}

namespace boost
{
    namespace serialization
    {
        template<class Archive>
        void load_construct_data( Archive& /*ar*/, Derived* d,
            const unsigned int /*v*/ )
        {
            ::new(d) Derived( 0 );
        }
    }
}

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY( Derived )

// Derived.cpp
#include "Derived.hpp"

Derived::Derived( int param ) : param_( param ) {}
Derived::~Derived(){}

Derived::foo()
{
    // some stuff
}

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT( Derived )

// Main.cpp
#include <boost/mpi.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

#include "Derived.hpp"

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    boost::shared_ptr< Base > sp;

    if ( world.rank() == 0 )
    {
        sp = boost::shared_ptr< Base >( new Derived( 5 ) );

        boost::mpi::broadcast( world, sp, 0 );

        // produce some stuff
    } else
    {
        while ( 1 )
        {
           // consume some stuff
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT( Base )
```

I found only one Google Groups discussion about this problem but no solution so far https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/boost-developers-archive/Ee9_ilEDO7s/cJTy-8v5lEcJ.  How can I get this to compile?  I am using openmpi 1.2.8-17.4, gcc 4.5.1 and boost 1.54.

Answer (score 1):

I was thankfully able to answer my own question (I think.)  Boost doesn't handle through-base-pointer serialization properly when combined with boost::mpi::packed_skeleton_iarchive.  The solution is then to use a different kind of archive, e.g. text_iarchive/text_oarchive, instead.

For example, to broadcast:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(oss);
oa << value;
std::string s = oss.str();
boost::mpi::broadcast(comm, s, root);
```

And to receive:

```
std::string s;
boost::mpi::broadcast(comm, s, root);
std::istringstream iss(s);
boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(iss);
ia >> value;
```